# Parsing JSON in C# without object names

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm a bit new to C# and having a bit of trouble parsing some nested JSON objects.

I'm making a GET request which returns some JSON. I've simplified it as much as possible to make it easy to go over. An example of the JSON response is:

```
{
"response": {
"ITEM1": {
  "RANDOM_DATE": {
    "mean": 150,
    "min": 150,
    "max": 150
  }
},
"ITEM2": {
  "RANDOM_DATE2": {
    "mean": 200,
    "min": 200,
    "max": 200
  },
  "RANDOM_DATE3": {
    "mean": 150,
    "min": 150,
    "max": 150
  }
}
}
}
```

What I currently have is:

```
dynamic response = JObject.Parse(await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url));
foreach (dynamic item in response["response"])           
{ 
    string name = item.ToString();
    string valueInCentsStr = "0";
    int valueInCents = 0;

    foreach (dynamic day in response["response"][item])
    {
        valueString = response["response"][item][day].min;
        valueInt = int.Parse(valueString);
    }
}
```

So right now item.ToString() is completely fine. That functions properly and returns ITEM1 and ITEM2.

The issue is, the nested object names are always different which is why I added a nested foreach to iterate through each ITEM to grab data from each day. However that doesn't seem to be working. I get an error pointing to that foreach saying:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.ArgumentException: Accessed JObject values with invalid key value:
```

I'm more accustomed to JavaScript and this worked fine in JS. How would you go about altering this to be able to grab information from the nested objects?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to pass element name to response indexer (like you do with `response["response"]), but you are passing element itself. Better avoid using dynamic and use benefits of compile-time type checks unless absolutely necessary (and here it is not).

Comment: Oh didn't see this response, I'll go back and change my other code. Not sure why I was making everything dynamic. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already using Json.NET, the easiest way to deserialize your JSON is to define the following types:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, DateValue>> response { get; set; }
}

public class DateValue
{
    public int mean { get; set; }
    public int min { get; set; }
    public int max { get; set; }
}
```

(You may need to change `mean`, `min` and `max` to be of type `decimal` or `double` if, in your actual JSON, these values can be fractional.)

Then deserialize as follows:

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response);
```

Relevant documentation: [Deserialize a Dictionary](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDictionary.htm).

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/i0QdkP).

Note that if your `"RANDOM_DATE"` strings are in fact in a `DateTime` format recognized by Json.NET (see [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/datesinjson.htm) for a list of such formats) you could define your `RootObject` as follows:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<DateTime, DateValue>> response { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. And yeah they are indeed actual dates but I only need the information in them, not the dates themselves. Thanks though :) Also, what would you recommend more. Your solution or Tadija's solution? I would normally do it with his solution but I've been seeing a lot of code like yours with C#.

Comment: As in @Evk's comment, my answer gives you the advantages of static typing which helps to protect against errors and ensure that the code works if it compiles.  This site also claims that deserialization to fixed types has slightly better performance: https://stackify.com/top-11-json-performance-usage-tips/.  But, as explained in the [tour] stackoverflow answers are mainly about *how* to do things not *which solution is best*.

Comment: Got it thanks and I was just curious at what I should be doing in the future. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: deserializing to classes rather than to dynamic is definitely more the norm and a good starting point. You can always optimize if that become too expensive